# How to rename a one file name with another file part name in the same directory?

Tags: linux, files, rename, unicode, database

the database I am using is Unix and I am trying to automate where I want it to rename the file for me when I run it instead of me going to file and manually rename it.

For example.

Two files in the same directory folder:

```
123.x12
abc_def_ghi_jkmnoo07122023064424.x12
```

I want the first file to be renamed only certain parts from the 2nd file to the first one.

```
123_def_ghi_07122023064424.x12
abc_def_ghi_jkmnoo07122023064424.x12
```

I know it can sound a bit complicated but I was wondering if it's possible. So in this case. The first file will be using only certain parts of the file name. _def_ghi and 07122023064424

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.